# Conditional Dynamic finder in grails

Tags: grails, dynamic-finders

so i require something like the dynamic finder should change as per the condition, let me explain by code what i mean

the below code find all employee by status and lastdateattended

```
    def employee = Employee.findAllByStatusAndLastDateAttended("INA",dateObject)
```

now i have two fields in Employee LastDateAttended and LastDateSigned , and now i want that if a record does not have  LastDateAttended, then it should find by LastDateSigned , otherwise LastDateAttended, so another condition is like

```
      def employee = Employee.findAllByStatusAndLastDateAttended("INA",dateObject)
```

and i somehow wants to join and use both the query based on a condition , can it be achieved ?, if possible please help

Comment: other than such a line of code would be unreadable long, i'd expect this not to work.  why not use one of the many ways grails provide to write a nice (understandable) query that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Employee.list().findAll { emp-> 
     emp.status == "INA" && ( emp.lastDateAttended!=null?
         emp.lastDateAttended.equals(dateObject):emp.lastDateSigned.equals(dateObject)
       ) 
}
```

Comment: this loads the whole list into your application.  the filtering should be done in the DB

Answer (score 2):

I think criteria query make sense here, something like following

```
Employee.createCriteria().list{
 and{
     eq('status','INA')
     or {
        eq('lastDateAttended',dateObject)
        eq('lastDateSigned',dateObject)
     }
  }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Employee.findAllByStatusOrLastDateAttendedOrStatusAndLastDateAttended("INA",dateObject)
```